# Folder /var/lib/mysql is missing after near 1 day

Tags: directory, mariadb

I have running OpenSuse Leap 15.3 with MariaDB 10.6.15.
The server running first normally after installation.
At this server runs a internal application (Apache with PHP 8) where i have access from outside over DynDNS with a open port at the router (not 3306) to MariaDB and the Application (web frontend with login).
Open Ports are MariaDB (not 3306), SSH (not 22), HTTPS (443) and HTTP (80) for testing.

I have set passwords for root, removed anonymous user and all looks fine.
After near one day are the subfolders of my databases missing in /var/lib/mysql/ and also some DB-files in the subfolder mysql.
Sometimes the MariaDB server is reseted like after new installation, so i see the database "test" (what i have normally deleted), root without password and all other databases are missing.

Now i changed the database folder (all works now fine) and only copied the entire mysql folder to /var/lib/mysql and after one day, this folder is again complete deleted.

So now my question is, is this posible with SQL-Injection (so i need to check my PHP code to prevent SQL-Injection) or do i need SSH Access, or is it a missconfiguration in the Apache Webserver so somebody hack our system?
It only affect the /var/lib/mysql folder every time.

changed default mariadb folder

Comment: You ALWAYS need to harden your code against SQL-Injection regardless of wether this is the reason for this problem

Comment: Why do you need any external access directly to mariaDB. Surely the application is what accesses the database and that is on the same machine as the database. I mean Apache and mariaDB are on the same machine so external access to mariaDB is not required

Comment: Without significant investigation, it's impossible to say what the problem is here. In any case, never open your database to the outside. If you need to access it directly for development or maintenance, you can SSH to the host first.

Comment: Thanks @ all. I think my PHP code is hardened, but i will check, this is also my idea.

Comment: I don't think it's possible for SQL injection to cause a problem like this. It can produce unwanted query results, but queries can't affect the directory structure.

Comment: So it's more likely that someone has hacked your system.

Comment: Yes, i think i have it.... how you say, SQL Injection i think also it is not possible to delete folders..... I had Publickey auth on and maybe someone had stolen my ppk file or my private key in authorized keys.... So i turned this off and changed the password so let`s see what happens.......